# IIS reverse proxy using ARR returning 502.3 Bad Gateway - Operation Timed Out for some requests

Tags: iis, spree, puma, windows-server-2019

We have a bunch of SaaS clients. Our SaaS client websites are on IIS on a Windows Server 2019. I have setup a spree commerce backend (hosted using Puma on a debian server) for our SaaS clients. The way it is set up right now is that the client frontends send a request to the IIS server that then gets reverse proxied to the spree backend.

Sometimes (about 10%-15% of the requests), when the frontend makes the request to the IIS server, it responds with 502.3 bad gateway, but it works if I refresh.

Initially I thought the issue was that the Spree backend wasn't responding. But checking the logs for the Puma server, it looks like the request didn't reach the Puma server.

I tried using Failed Request Tracing on IIS and also checked HTTPERR logs. The FRT logs mention `ARR_WEBFARM_NOT_ROUTED`.

FailedRequestTracing logs:

[image]

Looking at HTTPERR logs, it says Connection_Dropped. Here's a snippet of the HTTPERR logs:

```
#Software: Microsoft HTTP API 2.0
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2023-12-29 09:26:57
#Fields: date time c-ip c-port s-ip s-port cs-version cs-method cs-uri streamid sc-status s-siteid s-reason s-queuename
2024-01-03 21:50:58 209.115.235.218 64176 10.50.7.10 443 HTTP/2 POST /api/v2/storefront/cart 687 - 7 Connection_Dropped CANbearhouse
2024-01-03 21:50:58 209.115.235.218 64176 10.50.7.10 443 HTTP/2 GET /api/v2/storefront/products?include=primary_variant%2Cimages%2Cdefault_variant&page=1&per_page=12 703 - 7 Connection_Dropped CANbearhouse
2024-01-03 21:50:58 209.115.235.218 64176 10.50.7.10 443 HTTP/2 GET /api/v2/storefront/menus?locale=en&filter%5Blocation%5D=header&include=menu_items%2Cmenu_items.linked_resource%2Cmenu_items.icon 699 - 7 Connection_Dropped CANbearhouse
2024-01-03 21:50:58 209.115.235.218 64176 10.50.7.10 443 HTTP/2 GET /api/v2/storefront/menus?locale=en&filter%5Blocation%5D=footer&include=menu_items%2Cmenu_items.linked_resource%2Cmenu_items.icon 701 - 7 Connection_Dropped CANbearhouse
2024-01-03 21:50:58 209.115.235.218 64176 10.50.7.10 443 HTTP/2 GET /api/v2/storefront/cms_pages?filter%5Btype%5D=home&include=cms_sections.linked_resource 707 - 7 Connection_Dropped CANbearhouse
2024-01-03 21:50:58 209.115.235.218 64176 10.50.7.10 443 HTTP/2 GET /api/v2/storefront/taxons?filter%5Broots%5D=true&include=parent%2Ctaxonomy%2Cchildren%2Cimage 695 - 7 Connection_Dropped CANbearhouse
2024-01-03 21:50:58 209.115.235.218 64176 10.50.7.10 443 HTTP/2 GET /api/v2/storefront/products?include=primary_variant%2Cimages%2Cdefault_variant&page=1&per_page=12 693 - 7 Connection_Dropped CANbearhouse
2024-01-03 21:50:58 209.115.235.218 64176 10.50.7.10 443 HTTP/2 GET /api/v2/storefront/cart?include=line_items%2Cvariants%2Cvariants.images%2Cbilling_address%2Cshipping_address%2Cuser%2Cpayments%2Cshipments%2Cpromotions 697 - 7 Connection_Dropped CANbearhouse
2024-01-03 21:50:58 209.115.235.218 64176 10.50.7.10 443 HTTP/2 POST /api/v2/storefront/cart 711 - 7 Connection_Dropped CANbearhouse
2024-01-03 21:51:28 209.115.235.218 64176 10.50.7.10 443 HTTP/2 GET /api/v2/storefront/taxons/2?include=products&fields%5Bproduct%5D=id 683 - 7 Connection_Dropped CANbearhouse
2024-01-03 21:51:28 209.115.235.218 64176 10.50.7.10 443 HTTP/2 GET /api/v2/storefront/taxons/2?include=products&fields%5Bproduct%5D=id 747 - 7 Connection_Dropped CANbearhouse
2024-01-03 21:52:53 209.115.235.218 64176 10.50.7.10 443 HTTP/2 GET /api/v2/storefront/products?include=primary_variant%2Cimages%2Cdefault_variant&page=1&per_page=12 763 - 7 Connection_Dropped CANbearhouse
```

How do I go about fixing this? Thanks.

Comment: The `Connection_Dropped` error may mean that your web application is under heavy load and therefore no threads are currently available to provide logging data to HTTP.sys. I suggest you take a look at the IIS request queue to verify if the IIS server is overwhelmed with requests. Check the number of requests in the request queue and adjust the application pool settings if necessary.

Comment: I monitored concurrent requests in the application pool and it was about 10-15 requests concurrently being proxied. I don't think that's a big enough number to cause timeout issues? I have also added a picture of FRT logs above if that helps?

Comment: I looked at the picture of your FRT log and it looks like the request timed out. You can try increasing the timeout. In IIS Manager, right click on the site and go to Manage Web Site -> Advanced Settings. Under Connection Limits option, you should see Connection Time-out.

Comment: The timeout is set to 2 minutes. I don't think the timeout is the issue because when I monitor the puma server logs, the request isn't even being proxied to the server.

Comment: Perhaps you need to check for network connectivity issues and check for any network-related errors or packet loss.